# Create Tab but skip names that already exist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, tabs

I have the below code in Google Sheets which creates a number of tabs based on a list of names (on CVR tab), copying from a Template tab.

However this code only really works once, if new names are added after the tabs have been created it will create a "Exception: A sheet with the name ‘XXX’ already exists. Please enter another name."

How can I add the ability for the code to skip the name in the list if the tab already exists?

Thanks

```
function makeTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CVR");
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  //var Template = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();//identifies the last active row on the sheet
  
  //loop through the code until each row creates a tab.
  for(var i=0; i<last; i++){
    
   var tabName = sheet.getRange(i+8,1).getValue();//get the range in column A and get the value. 
    
    var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName);//create a new sheet with the value

var destination = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
destination.clear() 

var range = source.getRange(1,1,35, 15);  
range.copyTo(destination.getRange(1,1));

  }
}
```

Comment: Spreadsheet.getSheets() is list of all sheets. Check that every name on the CVR tab is not in the list. Use array.map , array.indexOf(), and maybe filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new sheets while avoiding names already being used

```
function makeTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName()).flat();//get the current sheet names
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("CVR");
  var src = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  var last = sh.getLastRow();//identifies the last active row on the sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < last; i++) {
    var tabName = sh.getRange(i + 8, 1).getValue();
    if (!~shts.indexOf(tabName)) {//if tabName is not in current sheet name list
      var nsh = ss.insertSheet(tabName);//this returns a Sheet Object
      nsh.clear();
      src.getRange(1, 1, 35, 15).copyTo(nsh.getRange(1, 1));
    }
  }
}
```

- [bitwise not ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: This is great but I'm also getting a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clear')" error message. Seems to be once i've added a new name to the list and then try and re-run I get that error, would the order of the new name in the list matter? i.e. If the list is sorted alphabetically and the new name populates in the middle of the list then I think this produces that error. The list is held inside a pivot table, which is sorting it. @Cooper

Comment: Sorry I madean error.  I think it's correct now.